# HTML, PHP No data in drop down box

Tags: php, ms-access, web, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out why a website's drop down box will not show any options. The data file for this drop down box comes from a microsoft access .mde file. The file is present and after the last update was working fine. Some changes happened to the site, i.e. text got added along with some photos. Im not saying this was when the drop down box went bad, but when it was discovered these were the only changes made. The data file seems fine as it is worked with everyday. 
      Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to begin looking for the bug?

For a better idea of what I am talking about, check out the Site h[ttp://yogaalliance.org/teacher_search.cfm](http://yogaalliance.org/teacher_search.cfm) and try selecting a country.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's really not enough information available for us to help you here - we aren't your personal debugging team.

Comment: The dataset that you use to render the country options must be empty. Debug (print / display / iterate) the result dataset that comes when querying your MS access file - it should be empty. Make sure that you are using the appropriate driver to access your .mde file and no exception occurs when you query for data.

Comment: Not asking you to debug, just point me in the right direction. I usually code in VHDL and objective C, so this is kinda new for me

Comment: An MDE with nothing in it but tables shows that whoever created it hasn't the slightest comprehension of the purpose of an MDE file. Anyone can read the help file and see why I would say this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="srchCountry" tabindex="1" onchange="changeCountry(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="none">Choose Country</option>
</select>
```

Post your code as there seems to be a problem with the script, not with the html.

Comment: This is all new to me, I ususally code in VHDL adn Objective C. There is a teachersearch.cfm, but that seems to assume there is already data. what other file extension are you looking for. .?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the code that renders the dropdown and trace where it gets its data, put some print statements with comments along the way so that you can look at the html output and see if there is any data there

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that's highly unlikely in a Cold Fusion file (I'm assuming the CFM extension means it's CF), and that's that the country table has had fields added to it, and the select is being populated from a SQL result set using ordinal references rather than field names, e.g., rs(0) instead of rs("Country"). If a new field was added in the table before the Country field, rs(0) would now return the first field instead of Country, which is now rs(1).

I would think it's extremely unlikely that this is the cause -- it's an explanation more likely to be applicable to 1999-era PHP code!

Answer (score -1):

The right direction can be only one and it is called "debugging".
As it can be thousands of reasons, you have to trace your application yourself, step by step, checking all critical variables values, trying to spot the place where the things goes bad.
Error messages are great help too

Good article from IBM to start from: shttp://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

The main thing to understand is the code must be **run** to find the problem, not overlooked.